# How to change values in column and generate a new DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, where-clause, mask

I have a DataFrame and I want to genera new one changing values from just one column, and keep original dataframe intact.I have try with mask, where and iloc, but the original data frame always change.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "age": [50, 40, 30, 40, 20, 10, 30],
  "qualified": [True, False, False, False, False, True, True]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

newdf = df
newdf["age"] = newdf.where(newdf["age"] > 30,2)

print(newdf)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
age  qualified
0  50       True
1  40      False
2   2      False
3  40      False
4   2      False
5   2       True
6   2       True
  age  qualified
0  50       True
1  40      False
2   2      False
3  40      False
4   2      False
5   2       True
6   2       True
```

Is there some way to change this values and keep the original?

Comment: Use: `newdf = df.copy(deep=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.copy(deep=True)` [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
  "age": [50, 40, 30, 40, 20, 10, 30],
  "qualified": [True, False, False, False, False, True, True]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# deep copy
newdf = df.copy(deep=True)


newdf["age"] = np.where(newdf["age"] > 30, newdf["age"], 2)
print(newdf)
   age  qualified
0   50       True
1   40      False
2    2      False
3   40      False
4    2      False
5    2       True
6    2       True

print(df)
   age  qualified
0   50       True
1   40      False
2   30      False
3   40      False
4   20      False
5   10       True
6   30       True
```